# How much do “where did you hear about us?” type questions impact signup/conversion rates?

Tags: forms, registration, conversion, marketing, ab-testing

There's a truism I often hear - claiming that the less complicated the signup process for a web-service, the higher the conversion rate (as a rough measure of complexity, count mouse clicks to signup completion).

Has anyone A/B tested or otherwise measured this impact and reported on their results, comparing a signup process with a "where did you hear about us?" form to one without?

Comment: It's not only the form completion that you can consider when deciding whether or not to include this particular field. With Google Analytics you can now *accurately* tell how they came to find your site. If you're putting a question on that they have to think about to answer you have no guarantee that the answer is actually correct. It's a meaningless field - how can you prove the people answering 'Recommended by a friend' *were* recommended by a friend? And if they were, so what? What actual use is this field anyway? Would you substantially change the site based on any of the answers?

Comment: Also: see some of the responses from this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/studies-showing-that-the-more-form-fields-there-are-the-less-conversions-you-wil

Comment: +1 @Jonw. blueberryfields, check out Analytics Campaigns - http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55540

Answer (score 10):

Honestly speaking from personal experience,the only time I would bother to answer the question is I was applying for a job and I felt that selecting "employee referral" (provided I was referred by an employee :) ) might get me an interview or atleast get my resume in front of a recruiter.

That said,every additional field that you require the user the fill up is preventing them from actually signing up and reducing your conversion rate.

This [article](http://www.imagescape.com/clients-like-you/contact-form/) actually found that reducing the number of fields from 11 to 4 increased the conversion rate by 64 %. The results summary of that

> - Number of forms submitted increased 140%
> - Conversion ratio increased 120%

Here is another [blog](http://blog.marketo.com/blog/2008/02/two-practical-l.html) which highlights the impact of shorter forms on increased conversion rates

That said,with regards to the question you had raised about the "How did you find about us field",this [article](http://www.ioninteractive.com/post-click-marketing-blog/2010/1/11/how-did-you-hear-about-me.html) gives some input about what happened to their form when they got rid of it. To summarize their results :

> Many years ago we had a client who was having the debate about whether
>   or not to include the ‘how did you hear about us?’ question on their
>   form. To solve it once and for all, they included a wacky choice in
>   the drop down— “billboard,” and although the client never ran a
>   billboard ad, this ended up being the most selected choice. Question
>   removed from form forever.

Answer (score 6):

This might be helpful. I'll remove it if it breaks the rules.

I once converted a long and gruelling sign up form and chopped it up into wizard-like steps and compared them A/B style. In both cases there was a "Where did you hear about us?" field (I failed to get stakeholders to allow me to drop it).

In both cases it was an optional step and I found that the field was completed way more often in the wizard version than in the long form.