# How Many Fields Is Too Many on Mobile Form?

Tags: mobile

I come from a website background but making a mobile app right now.

I need to get data from people that will possibly be standing in a store and might be turned off if I come with too many fields to fill out but I don't really know how many is too many.

I right now have 9 textboxes that I would like the user to fill out but I am not sure if that would be too much to show at once.

I am thinking maybe having 2 tabs or something like that with "basic" information and "Optional" information.

I still would have 7 textbox shown to the user right away and I am still not sure if that is too many and might turn them off.

Anyone know from experience when users start to feel it is too much work and just give up?

6 of the 7 fields will be number entry and select list entry. 1 will be a free entry box.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/studies-showing-that-the-more-form-fields-there-are-the-less-conversions-you-wil

Comment: Hi chobo2, welcome to UX.se! Currently your question is quite open ended and quite hard to get one specific answer. Can you provide additional details on your form and add a mockup/screenshot?

Comment: @JamesJenkins, The link you provided is a very interesting reference to look at, but it's really about web forms that you'd fill out with a PC and a big physical keyboard, not forms that you'd fill out with a mobile phone. Chobo2, please definitely provide more information. Also, tell us if you've considered using Facebook login information, or gps information, and other sensor information, to infer some of the information required instead of asking for it explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

Chobo2, don't rush for numbers! Please read [The Complexity of Simplicity](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/12/the-complexity-of-simplicity.php), which can break the myth "the less is the best".

So the recipe for you could be like:

1. Define all *necessary* data you want from user
2. Group the data by logical pieces
3. Order the pieces to create logical flow
4. Use tricks/hacks to simplify user input