# Does anyone have data or statistics on how forcing users to reveal gender during registration effects conversions

Tags: registration, gender

We are currently working with a client that insists that users have to state their gender during the registration process for a streaming service (for marketing purposes). We really do not want to ask the users this since it may offend. I was wondering if anyone has any references or data on how these types of irrelevant questions about the user affects conversions.

Comment: This question has some useful links: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/studies-showing-that-the-more-form-fields-there-are-the-less-conversions-you-wil In summary - the more fields are present the lower the conversion percentage. And more complex fields (such a select boxes, which you are probably using for gender) have greater impact on that conversion rate than just plain text fields. So regardless of the fact it is Gender being asked for, just the fact that *anything* is being requested is going to reduce conversions.

Answer (score 3):

A couple thoughts:

- I found [this article](http://itspronouncedmetrosexual.com/2012/06/how-can-i-make-the-gender-question-on-an-application-form-more-inclusive/). Worth the read. I gathered that this appears to be a sensitive topic and, thus, it might not go over well in a registration form for a streaming service.
- If you're a Google Analytics user, consider enabling [Demographics and Interests](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819950?hl=en) so you can glean that data but not force the user to answer a question. You may not have a direct tie to your users, but this would give you a general idea of demographics on registered users.

[image: Description of available data from Google Analytics' Demographics and Interests]

Answer (score 0):

This [article on how to increase conversion rates](http://conversionxl.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-increasing-ecommerce-conversion-rates/) doesn't mention anything specific about gender, but it does tell you to keep forms short, and offer people the option to buy without registering for your site (which would imply not asking for their gender, because they haven't registered).